# Display the category notes on the page "article manager"

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I use the category note field as a reminder for the "article template" I use for the articles in that category.

An example of a category note: always add module 20 (using module anywhere) at the bottom of the article.

To save me time I would like to display this note when I am on the article manager page so that I can see it just before I click on "create a new article".

EDIT:
Another way of doing it, could be to have sticky notes on backend, or an extra field in the article editing page so that I can see this reminder. 
Note that simply adding another field to the article as describe [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin) won't work as I don't want to add new info on each article but rather the opposite: the same reminder should be display on all articles.

Comment: Which version of joomla?

Comment: @cppl Joomla 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. you could do an admin template override of the com_content component HOWEVER why not use a nice content templater such as

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/contenttemplater

This will allow you to create as many templates as you want

You could for example create a template for each category, and then you create a new article, with that template autoloading all default content such as the {modules anywhere code}, languages, meta data will just appear, then you just add the unique content.

No notes, just a much more efficient system by one of the best Joomla authors in the business who you are already using

to quote direct from the site

*Automatically load template
You can set templates to load as default. This way, the template will be loaded when you create a new article (or other content item). You can limit templates to certain sections / categories. So you can define different default templates per category.*

Comment: That's really a great idea! I haven't thought about my problem this way and thanks to you, I get an easy solution! And as for the good promo for Nonumber... he deserves it!